# Update MySQL table from jsp

Tags: mysql, database, jsp

I have these in a jsp file. But these values are not updated in the mysql table. May be it is not commiting. How can i solve this ?

```
String passc1 = request.getParameter("passc1");
String accid = request.getParameter("accid");
int i = 0;

String sql =
        " update customertb "
        + " set passwd = ?"
        + " where acc_no = ?;";

try {
   PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, passc1);
    ps.setString(2, accid);

    i = ps.executeUpdate();
} catch (Exception e) {
    // do something with Exception here. Maybe just throw it up again
} finally {
    con.close();

}
```

**Stacktrace**

Apr 01, 2012 11:29:02 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /changepwd_done.jsp at line 81

```
      e.printStackTrace();
 } finally {
     //con.close();
     con.commit();
 }
```

Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.sql.SQLException: Can't call commit when autocommit=true
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:936)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:933)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.commit(ConnectionImpl.java:1635)
    at org.apache.jsp.changepwd_005fdone_jsp._jspService(changepwd_005fdone_jsp.java:160)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:433)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:389)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:333)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:100)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:929)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:405)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:964)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:515)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:304)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Comment: the code seems to be correct... can you print the stack trace on the error? and paste the stack trace here

Comment: You can't invoke commit method when autocommit=true. Remove that method call or set autocommit=false first, con.setAutocommit(false)

Comment: Yup remove that method in your JSP file, `commit` and it will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Catch SQLException and check the console messages:

```
[...]

try {
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.setString(1, passc1);
    ps.setString(2, accid);
    i = ps.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I bet accountid is a integer and he is saying it is a string. Nevertheless, this answer would help him find the solution. He should never write a comment like that for an extension. He should use proper logging utils like log4j or equivalent to manage logging for him.

Comment: Yeah, i guess so. Hope that helped him to figure it out the solution :-)